# Is it possible to create points that automatically resize with cex?

Tags: r, mapping

The following data represents a number of geographical points with associated revenue :

```
df1 <- data.frame(lat = c(36.75, 46.21, 32.31, 29.5, 35.46), long = c(-88.79, -97.8, -106.79, -82.28, -97.51), revenue = c(15000, 10000, 4000, 30000, 12000))
```

The following code plots the points on a map:

```
plot(map, xlim = c(-130, -65), ylim = c(35,40), asp = 1)
points(df1$long, df1$lat, col="red", pch=16, cex=0.0003*df1$revenue)
```

In order to create the map above, I’ve made "cex" equal revenue * 0.0003.

As I’m dealing with large revenue quantities, I need to multiply the value by an extremely small fraction of one in order to make the map visually amenable.

Is it possible to size the points automatically, in such a way that one can simply enter “1”, “2”, “3” etc. in such a way that the points will automatically resize to a natural size? In the status quo, I have to fiddle around with extremely small numbers to make this work.

(For reference, I’m thinking of something along the lines of the “size” function of a plot in ggplot2.)

Comment: something like `scales::rescale` ?

Comment: @StephenKaroly: Just so you understand, the `scales` package would be needed for rawr's suggestion. Modifying an existing plot would involve redrawing the points with higher cex.

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict the `cex` value to fall within a certain range like this. I'm not familiar with `scales::rescale` from the comments, but maybe this does the same thing

```
# set the minimum and maximum cex values
cex_min <- 1
cex_max <- 4

df1 <- data.frame(lat = c(36.75, 46.21, 32.31, 29.5, 35.46), long = c(-88.79, -97.8, -106.79, -82.28, -97.51), revenue = c(15000, 10000, 4000, 30000, 12000))

df1$revenue2 <- df1$revenue - min(df1$revenue)
df1$proportion <- df1$revenue2 / max(df1$revenue2)
df1$cex_val <- cex_min + df1$proportion * (cex_max - cex_min)

plot(map, xlim = c(-130, -65), ylim = c(35,40), asp = 1)
points(df1$long, df1$lat, col="red", pch=16, cex=df1$cex_val)
```